# Python3 - error installing jwt with pip3 on Ubuntu 14

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, jwt

After know that jwt package is incompatible with python2, I am trying to install it with pip3:

```
sudo pip3 install jwt
```

I am getting the following output:

> Exception:
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2482, in
>   _dep_map
>      return self.**dep_map
>
>      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2344, in
>   __getattr**
>      raise AttributeError(attr) AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)
>    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
>       requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
>     File
>   "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1266, in
>   prepare_files
>       req_to_install.extras):
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2291, in
>   requires
>       dm = self._dep_map   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2484, in
>   _dep_map
>       self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
>    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2508, in
>   _compute_dependencies
>       parsed = next(parse_requirements(distvers))
>    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2605, in
>   parse_requirements
>       line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")
>    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line
>   2583, in scan_list
>       "Expected ',' or end-of-list in",line,"at",line[p:] ValueError: ("Expected ',' or end-of-list in", 'cryptography <2.*,>=1.7.2', 'at',
>   '*,>=1.7.2')

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved problem. I had to upgrade pip3:

```
pip3 install --upgrade
```

After this, I am able to install jwt with the following:

```
pip3 install jwt
```